# CVXPY: objective function to have solution equals to each other

Tags: python, cvxpy

I would like to have CVXPY solve a maximization problem where objective function is  a summation over [0,i]. However, I want the same solution for all x[0,i]

I tried the code as displayed here but solution to x are not the same.

```
x = Variable(10)
g= 0
for i in range(inflist[0],inflist[-1]+1):
    g+= "some function here"

prob = cp.Problem(Maximize(g))
prob.solve()

z= x.value
z
```

I can optimize over the summation but solution to x are not the same

Comment: why use vector of size 10 when you need all of its values to be the same?

Comment: Hi, that was something I tried previously (had 10 solutions to x). When I place Variable(1), the answer returns null

Comment: @SohaibJundi Sorry, i was a fool. I mistyped something. setting it as variable(1) works magically now